# Python: Selenium write in the text box of a frame/form/table

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to write in the text box in this html code with python

I tried something like:

```
frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
        
for f in frames:
      print ("FRAMES ID:", f.get_attribute('id'),"Frame names", f.get_attribute('name'))
      id_report = f.get_attribute('id')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id(id_report)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*\[@id='b_s2_s11_l2s11_ctl00_reg_period<>_i'\]"))
elem.click()
```

HTML --> [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9i50.jpg)

But when I do that I get this error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: It would be useful to know the whole stack, to also understand where it is exploding... Though I agree with the given answer: I believe that what you'd like to extract with Selenium is dynamically generated, making it harder to get it via a small selector. Something that you could accomplish might using something like //*[@class='Plain']//*[2]/tbody/tr/td (though I'm not sure if it should be [1] or [2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like a dynamically generated id, which means it is different in every session. Try to run a non-headless browser with your script and check if the id is different. If so, you should use a different locator.
I could help more, if I had the url or at least the html you want to automate.

Comment: thk very much ptzanis i attached the html like image ... becouse i can't copy the HTML from source page....